# How can I prevent CSS animations until the page scrolls to a certain fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

I have landing page (one page) website. I have text in the center of the landing page that is highlighted with CSS animation. Unfortunately, the CSS animation that highlights this text is performed immediately after entering the website. How can I stop it? How to make an animation run with text only when it appears on the screen. Now the text shows up when the user scrolls and it works. Unfortunately, the underline moves earlier after entering the website. When the user scrolls the page, the text is underlined :(

```
<h2 class=" title animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".4">lorem <span class="text-nice-underline">ipsum</span> <span class="text-nice-underline2" >example</span> template</h2>
```

[Screenshot of this element](https://prnt.sc/10o5lxl)

```
.text-nice-underline  {
 position: relative;
}
.text-nice-underline:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1; /* Place the pseudo element right under the content */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffbc42 22%, transparent 24%);
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: 2.95s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.text-nice-underline2  {
    position: relative;
}
.text-nice-underline2:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1; /* Place the pseudo element right under the content */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffbc42 22%, transparent 24%);
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: 3.95s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  

}
.text-nice-underline2:hover, .text-nice-underline:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffbc42 95%, transparent 95%);
}
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  90% {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how do you want to trigger the animation. That's why I can't help for Javascript part, but the idea is to create a function that will check if the condition of animation is met, and will run the line down below.

```
const runAnimation = () => {
  if(your conditions) {
    document.querySelector(".text-nice-underlined").classList.add("animate");
  }
}
```

```
.text-nice-underlined.animate:after {
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: 2.95s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

You need to remove those 4 animation properties from text-nice-underlined:after

Comment: I want the animation not to run after entering the website. I want it to run (i.e. the text should be underlined) only when the user sees the text. Then it should take off.

Comment: I want to achieve the same effect like here: https://essentials.pixfort.com/seo/features/   but only when user scroll my page (one landing page) to the middle

Comment: In this case, you need to call that function without if-check on page load.

Comment: Ok but how? Can You help me? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can use js/jquery event Listener like this

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  const el = $('#myDiv');
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

  if(el == scrollPosition) {
    document.querySelector(".text-nice-underlined").classList.add("animate");
   }
});
```

when scroll is on your div(element you want) position animation will start

Answer (score 0):

On your animate class, add `animation-play-state: paused;`, now have another selector

```
.text-nice-underlined.animate.run-animation::after {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Now add an event to your body tag `document.body.addEventListener('scroll', e => { ... })`

and inside it you want to keep checking for whether your element/elements are in view using:

```
let elementInView = el.offsetTop < window.scrollY + document.documentElement.clientHeight

if (elementInView) {
  el.classList.add('run-animation')
}
```

*Hope this works for you, I have read somewhere though that hijacking or listening to scroll events is not the best thing to do performance wise, I hope someone sheds more light on this.*

EDIT: You will only need to do this if you have some special animation of yours, if you just need to add in that subtle fade-in animation to your page, consider trying out [this library](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)